# How can I divide hours to next working days in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table that stores the start-date and number of the hours. I have also another time table as reference to working days. My main goal is the divide this hours to the working days.

For examle:

```
ID   Date         Hour
1     20210504     40
```

I want it to be structured as

```
ID      Date         Hour
1       20210504     8
1       20210505     8
1       20210506     8
1       20210507     8
1       20210510     8
```

I manage to divide the hours with the given code but couldn't manage to make it in working days.

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(
  select 1 AS ID, 20210504 AS Date, 40 AS Hours --just a test case
), working_days AS 
(
select date from dateTable
),
cte2 AS 
(
select ID, Date, Hours, IIF(Hours<=8, Hours, 8) AS dailyHours FROM cte1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
cte2.ID,
cte2.Date + 1
,cte2.Hours - 8
,IIF(Hours<=8, Hours, 8)
FROM cte2
JOIN cte1 t ON cte2.ID = t.ID
WHERE cte2.HOURS > 8 AND cte2.Date + 1 IN (select * from working_days)
```

When I use it like this it only gives me this output with one day missing

```
ID      Date         Hour
1       20210504     8
1       20210505     8
1       20210506     8
1       20210507     8
```

Comment: which dbms are you using? tag it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to build your calendar in the right way,
adding also to `working_days` a `ROW_NUMBER` to get correct progression.

```
declare @date_start date = '2021-05-01'

;WITH
cte1 AS (
    SELECT * FROM 
    (VALUES
    (1, '20210504', 40),
    (2, '20210505', 55),
    (3, '20210503', 44)
    ) X (ID, Date, Hour)
),
numbers as (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by o.object_id) N
    FROM sys.objects o
),
cal as (
    SELECT cast(DATEADD(day, n, @date_start) as date) d, n-1 n
    FROM numbers n
    where n.n<32
),
working_days  as (
    select d, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by n) dn
    from cal
    where DATEPART(weekday, d) < 6 /* monday to friday in italy (country dependent) */
),
base as (
    SELECT t.ID, t.Hour, w.d, w.dn
    from cte1 t
    join working_days w on w.d = t.date
)
SELECT t.ID, w.d, iif((8*n)<=Hour, 8, 8 + Hour - (8*n) ) h
FROM base t
join numbers m on m.n <= (t.Hour / 8.0) + 0.5
join working_days w on w.dn = t.dn + N -1
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem and gave me a good idea of how to follow two different values in different tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE.  This should do the trick:

```
with cte as (
      select id, date, 8 as hour, hour as total_hour
      from t
      union all
      select id, dateadd(day, 1, date), 
             (case when total_hour < 8 then total_hour else 8 end),
             total_hour - 8
      from cte
      where total_hour > 0
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Note:  This assumes that `total_hour` is at least 8, just to avoid a `case` expression in the anchor part of the CTE.  That can trivially be added.

Also, if there might be more than 100 days, you will need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: How this could achieve the problem of the weekdays? I want it to pass the holidays and jump into Monday from Friday.