# Complex query analyzing historical records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle and trying to retrieve the total number of days a person was out of the office during the year. I have 2 tables involved:

### Statuses

```
1 - Active
2 - Out of the Office
3 - Other
```

### ScheduleHistory

```
RecordID - primary key
PersonID
PreviousStatusID
NextStatusID
DateChanged
```

I can easily find when the person went on vacation and when they came back, using

```
SELECT DateChanged FROM ScheduleHistory WHERE PersonID=111 AND NextStatusID = 2
```

and

```
SELECT DateChanged FROM ScheduleHistory WHERE PersonID=111 AND PreviousStatusID = 2
```

But in case a person went on vacation more than once, how can I can I calculate total number of days a person was out of the office. Is it possible to do programmatically, given only PersonID?

Here is some sample data:

```
RecordID    PersonID    PreviousStatusID    NextStatusID    DateChanged
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           111           1                     2              03/11/2020
2           111           2                     1              03/13/2020
3           111           1                     3              04/01/2020
4           111           3                     1              04/07/2020
5           111           1                     2              06/03/2020
6           111           2                     1              06/05/2020
7           111           1                     2              09/14/2020
8           111           2                     1              09/17/2020
```

So from the data above, for the year 2020 for PersonID 111 the query should return 7

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  From what you describe, you might have a record for each day and then you just add them up.  Also, what about time periods that go over a year boundary?  How are those handled?

Comment: This is just for a specified timeframe - 1 year. I added sample data

Comment: Do you count weekends as out of office?

Comment: weekends currently not in scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with aux1 AS (
    SELECT
        a.*,
        to_date(datechanged, 'MM/DD/YYYY') - LAG(to_date(datechanged, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) OVER(
            PARTITION BY personid
            ORDER BY
                recordid
        ) lag_date
    FROM
        ScheduleHistory a
) 
SELECT
    personid,
    SUM(lag_date) tot_days_ooo
FROM
    aux1
WHERE
    previousstatusid = 2
GROUP BY
    personid;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want total days (or weekdays) for each year (and to account for periods when it goes over the year boundary) then:

```sql
WITH date_ranges ( personid, status, start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT personid,
         nextstatusid,
         datechanged,
         LEAD(datechanged, 1, datechanged) OVER(
           PARTITION BY personid
           ORDER BY datechanged
         )
  FROM   table_name
),
split_year_ranges ( personid, year, start_date, end_date, max_date ) AS (
  SELECT personid,
         TRUNC( start_date, 'YY' ),
         start_date,
         LEAST(
           end_date,
           ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( start_date, 'YY' ), 12 )
         ),
         end_date
  FROM   date_ranges
  WHERE  status = 2
UNION ALL
  SELECT personid,
         end_date,
         end_date,
         LEAST( max_date, ADD_MONTHS( end_date, 12 ) ),
         max_date
  FROM   split_year_ranges
  WHERE  end_date < max_date
)
SELECT personid,
       EXTRACT( YEAR FROM year) AS year,
       SUM( end_date - start_date ) AS total_days,
       SUM(
         ( TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
         + LEAST( end_date - TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ), 5 )
         - LEAST( start_date - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ), 5 )
       ) AS total_weekdays
FROM   split_year_ranges
GROUP BY personid, year
ORDER BY personid, year
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( RecordID, PersonID, PreviousStatusID, NextStatusID, DateChanged ) AS
SELECT  1, 111, 1, 2, DATE '2020-03-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 111, 2, 1, DATE '2020-03-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 111, 1, 3, DATE '2020-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 111, 3, 1, DATE '2020-04-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 111, 1, 2, DATE '2020-06-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 111, 2, 1, DATE '2020-06-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 111, 1, 2, DATE '2020-09-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 111, 2, 1, DATE '2020-09-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 222, 1, 2, DATE '2019-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 222, 2, 2, DATE '2020-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 222, 2, 2, DATE '2021-01-02' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PERSONID | YEAR | TOTAL_DAYS | TOTAL_WEEKDAYS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 111 | 2020 | 7 | 7 |
> | 222 | 2019 | 1 | 1 |
> | 222 | 2020 | 366 | 262 |
> | 222 | 2021 | 1 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9db3224fe00cfca95d8eca89c4cbb2f3)*

Answer (score 0):

Provided no vacation crosses a year boundary

```
with grps as (
    SELECT sh.*,
      row_number() over (partition by PersonID, NextStatusID order by DateChanged) grp
    FROM ScheduleHistory sh
    WHERE NextStatusID in (1,2) and 3 not in (NextStatusID, PreviousStatusID)
), durations as (
    SELECT PersonID, min(DateChanged) DateChanged, max(DateChanged) - min(DateChanged) duration  
    FROM grps
    GROUP BY PersonID, grp
)
SELECT PersonID, sum(duration) days_out
FROM durations
GROUP BY PersonID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=050e33cb89630a88e4a03fd711d99b35)

Comment: somehow your query returns crazy number at the end, 117 instead of 7. I did have to remove the where clause from grps as next or previous status can really be anything. Status can go from 3 to 2 or 1 to 2. There could also be additional statuses

Answer (score 0):

`year_span` is used to split an interval spanning across two years in two different records

`H1` adds a row number dependent from PersonID to get the right sequence for each person

`H2` gets the periods for each status change and extract 1st day of the year of the interval end

`H3` split records that span across two years and calculate the right date_start and date_end for each interval

`H` calculates days elapsed in each interval for each year

final query sum up the records to get output

**EDIT**

If you need workdays instead of total days, you should not use `total_days/7*5` because it is a bad approximation and in some cases gives weird results.

I have posted a solution to jump on fridays to mondays [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386891/how-can-i-divide-hours-to-next-working-days-in-sql/67388738#67388738)

```
with 
statuses (sid, sdescr) as (
    select 1, 'Active' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Out of the Office' from dual union all
    select 3, 'Other' from dual 
),
ScheduleHistory(RecordID, PersonID, PreviousStatusID,  NextStatusID , DateChanged) as (
   select 1, 111, 1, 2, date '2020-03-11' from dual union all
   select 2, 111, 2, 1, date '2020-03-13' from dual union all
   select 3, 111, 1, 3, date '2020-04-01' from dual union all
   select 4, 111, 3, 1, date '2020-04-07' from dual union all
   select 5, 111, 1, 2, date '2020-06-03' from dual union all
   select 6, 111, 2, 1, date '2020-06-05' from dual union all
   select 7, 111, 1, 2, date '2020-09-14' from dual union all
   select 8, 111, 2, 1, date '2020-09-17' from dual union all
    SELECT  9, 222, 1, 2, date '2019-12-31' from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 222, 2, 2, date '2020-12-01' from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 222, 2, 2, date '2021-01-02' from dual 
), 
year_span (n) as (
   select 1 from dual union all
   select 2 from dual 
),
H1 AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY RecordID) PID, H.*
    FROM ScheduleHistory H
),
H2 as (
    SELECT 
        H1.*, H2.DateChanged DateChanged2, 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM H2.DateChanged) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM H1.DateChanged) + 1 Y,
        trunc(H2.DateChanged,'YEAR') Y2
    FROM H1 H1
    LEFT JOIN H1 H2 ON H1.PID = H2.PID-1 AND H1.PersonID = H2.PersonID
),
H3 AS (
    SELECT Y, N, H2.PID, H2.RecordID, H2.PersonID, H2.NextStatusID,
    CASE WHEN Y=1 THEN H2.DateChanged ELSE CASE WHEN N=1 THEN H2.DateChanged ELSE Y2 END END D1,
    CASE WHEN Y=1 THEN H2.DateChanged2 ELSE CASE WHEN N=1 THEN Y2 ELSE H2.DateChanged2 END END D2 
    FROM H2
    JOIN year_span N ON N.N <=Y
),
H AS (
    SELECT PersonID, NextStatusID, EXTRACT(year FROM d1) Y, d2-d1 D
    FROM H3
)
select PersonID, sdescr Status, Y, sum(d) d
from H
join statuses s on NextStatusID = s.sid
group by PersonID, sdescr, Y
order by PersonID, sdescr, Y
```

output

```
PersonID    Status              Y       d
111         Active              2020    177
111         Other               2020    6
111         Out of the Office   2020    7
222         Out of the Office   2019    1
222         Out of the Office   2020    366
222         Out of the Office   2021    1
```

check the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1bde5c841e5ba62b58ea9b10a1f5c8b0)